# Inputing multiple doubles on a single line in c using scanf and loops without array

Tags: c, algorithm, math, input, io

My program is suppose to read multiple inputs and display the min, max, sum and the average.  It is supposed to look like this:

Input:

```
2.5 5 3.5 4.5 jfkjk
```

output:

```
min is 2.5
max is 5
sum is 15.5
average is 3.875
```

The program is supposed to quit when it reaches a non-number or a newline. The user can input as many numbers as they like. I cannot use arrays and must use loops.
This is what my program looks like:

```
void numbers()
      {
      double digit;
      double sum = 0;
      double avg = 0;
      double max;
      double min;
      unsigned count = 0;
      //int c;
      max = 0;
      printf("Input:");

      do {
          scanf("%lf", &digit);

          min = digit;
          if(max < digit)
              digit = max;
          if(min < digit)
              digit = min;
          sum += digit;
          count++;
          avg = sum/count;
      } while( scanf("%lf", &digit)==1 )

      printf(" min is %lf max is %lf sum is %lf avg is %lf count is %u", min, max, sum, avg, count);
      }
```

prints out:

```
Input:2.2 2.3 5 3.5 blah 
 min is 3.500000 max is 0.000000 sum is 0.000000 avg is 0.000000 count is 4
```

Comment: First check your program with correct input and then try further.see Liho answer and use one scanf with loop and move scanf inside loop to before do.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 quite unpleasant errors hidden in your code:

- the way `min` and `max` are (not) being updated while iterating numbers

  This:

  ```
  if(max < digit)
       digit = max;
  if(min < digit)            // <-- the comparison for min is incorrect as well
       digit = min;
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  if(max < digit)
      max = digit;
  if(min > digit)         
      min = digit;
  ```

  since you want to update `min` / `max`, not the `digit` that has been read.
- logic of your loop

  This:

  ```
  do {
      scanf("%lf", &digit);
      ...
  } while( scanf("%lf", &digit)==1 )
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  while( scanf("%lf", &digit)==1 ) {
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: With these edits, `min` is not initialized.  Suggest `double min = +Big number` and `max = -Big number`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is truly important to:
-- 1) User can input as many numbers as they like.
-- 2) Quit when it reaches a non-number or a newline.
-- 3) No arrays.
then reading in data is challenging.

We must deal with an input line that goes on and on.....
We must distinguish between new-line `\n` and other white-space `char`.

Following OP style, let's do the white-space parsing manually and then let `scanf()` read the number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

  ...
  double sum = 0.0;
  double avg = 0.0;
  double max = 0.0;
  double min = 0.0;
  unsigned count = 0;
  int done = 0;
  while (1) {
    double x;
    int ch;
    do {
      ch = getchar();
      if ((ch == '\n') || (ch == EOF)) {
        done = 1;
        break;
      }
    } while (isspace(ch));
    if (done || (1 != scanf("%lf", &x))) break;
    // Cope with first `x`.
    // Could instead be done with `max` initialized to -DBL_MAX, min = DBL_MIN
    if (count++ == 0) {
      min = max = x;
    } else {
      if (x < min) min = x;
      if (x > max) min = x;
    }
    sum += x; 
    // OP had the following inside the loop - nicely avoids potential /0 outside loop
    avg = sum/count;  
  }
```